# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android, android-manifest

first of all i am new to Android,
i have imported an eclipse project to android studio. On building project it is showing this error

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

my code is as follows,

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.my.app" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.2">
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" />
    <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" />
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
    <!-- Permission - Internet Connect -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Allows the API to access Google web-based services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- Allows the API to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />


 <!--
        Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.
        NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
           where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
        -->
    <permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application android:name="com.my.app.util.HotelApp" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.HomeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.CategoryActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.ContactUSActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.LeisuresActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.LeisureActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.PromosActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.ReservationActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.AboutUsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.ReservationContinueActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.BookTableActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.AccommodationsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.CorporatesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.GuestServicesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.my.app.activity.PhotoGalleryActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <!--<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDAk_PM9Ce-z_9onkItz4aSahE1AGSBKDo" />-->
        <!--
          BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
          services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

          The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
          so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
        -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.my.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
          Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
          handle received messages.

          By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
          application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.
        -->
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and for build.gradle as follows

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stgeorge.hotel"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

i have tried other solutions provided here on stack overflow but none worked

Comment: "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" to help you it would be great if you would include the logs.

Comment: Please check error tab @bottom right hand side.

Comment: "I have tried other solutions" is too vague.. **what** did you try?

Comment: `app:processDebugManifest` means there is likely something wrong with the manifest. Please [edit] to show its full contents

Comment: i have tried changing sdk versions

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project again ?

Comment: thanks, but tried that too.. nothing worked

Comment: Could someone tell me where to even find the logs?

Answer (score 121):

from manifest you can see the error log. check the image

[image]

Comment: Since Android Studio gets changed all the time, the screenshot above is meaningless to current users.

Answer (score 5):

Remove sdk configuration from manifest file, in android studio we need to define in build.gradle only

and also change compileSdkVersion and buildToolVersion to your targeted sdk or change your target sdk to 23

 

***Note:-*** compileSdkVersion and buildToolVersion should belongs to same API level

Comment: The manifest overrides the Gradle configuration. You are able to define in both

Comment: There is also nothing wrong with having a lower target than the compile SDK

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by simply removing the empty/unused **intent filter** inside an activity tag in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

add the line your build.gradle
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this happens if you added a service - Android Studio *automatically* adds

```
<service
        android:name=".nameofyourclass"
```

and if you add another `<service` line of the type you wanted to make, that's a conflict. Check for duplicate service per file.