# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs. On building project it is showing this error

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have tried to search for the solution and its like I'm navigating to no where.
I have tried this solution:

[Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444149/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-see-logs)

but wont help me

This is my **manifest** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:activitytools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    package="technerd.com.iboda">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


    <dist:module dist:instant="true"

      />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
            android:name=".onAppKilled"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />

        <activity android:name=".HistorySingle"/>
        <activity android:name=".HistoryActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".DriverSettings" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUp" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".DriverMapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_maps" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CustomerMapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customer_maps" />
        <activity android:name=".DriverLogin" />
        <activity android:name=".CustomerLogin" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error log in merged manifest

Merging Errors:

**Error: Attribute**

> activity#com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity@theme value=(@style/PlacesAutocompleteThemeOverlay) from AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-66 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-61 value=(@style/PlacesAutocompleteOverlay). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-23:20 to override. app main manifest (this file), line 20

**Error: Attribute**

> activity#com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity@windowSoftInputMode value=(stateAlwaysVisible|adjustPan) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:13-71 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:19:13-55 value=(adjustResize). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:windowSoftInputMode"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-23:20 to override. app main manifest (this file), line 21

Comment: Also post your module level `build.gradle`

Comment: check out this link it will help you : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge  And also check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981156/tools-replace-not-replacing-in-android-manifest