# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs android studio error

Tags: android, manifest

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
When I upgraded my targetSDK from 30 to 31 this error shows
and when I go to Merged Manifest it shows the error bellow in the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA4dr.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444149/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-see-logs)